# ReactJS: post request with data through fetch

Tags: reactjs

In my app component, I have state `features` that contains an array(1500) of arrays(9). I want to send the state (or large array) to my backend so I can run my model and return labels with the following function:

```
const getLabels = (model) => {
    fetch('/spotify/get-labels', {headers: {
      'model': model,
      'features': features
    }})
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => setLabels(data))
}
```

However, the response has status 431. This was kinda expected, but I'm not sure how to transmit the data to my backend efficiently. Maybe convert it to json and then put in the headers of my request?

Comment: _"Maybe convert it to json"_ - yes; _"then put in the headers of my request"_ - no. Pass it in the body of the request. See: [Using fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Specifically see: [Uploading JSON data](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#uploading_json_data) section of the previously linked article.

Comment: Why is Axios better?

Comment: Read more about it --> https://blog.logrocket.com/axios-or-fetch-api/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like this with `fetch`:

```
fetch('/spotify/get-labels', {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({ model, features }),
})
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    // Boom!
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // An error happened!
  });
```

or with `axios`

```
axios
  .post('/spotify/get-labels', { model, features })
  .then((data) => {
    // Boom!
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    // An error happened!
  });
```

Comment: I get why Axios is preferred from this comparison already

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm understanding your concern, I guess passing the `'model': model,'features': features` in body should work.

Or using Axios, you can make the request. It exactly like Axios but far better

```
axios({
      url: '/spotify/get-labels',
      method: "post",
      data: {
        'model': model,
      'features': features
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(data => setLabels(data))
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error : ", JSON.parse(error));
      });
```

Comment: No that returns 431

Comment: in headers include 'Content-Type' : 'application/json'

Comment: I appreciate the effort but the solution was in JSON.stringify, otherwise the large array of data is posted as a query string which exceeds a limit and therefor returns 431